# Efficiently sort each and every row of a pandas data frame by reference to a predefined relation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, row

I have a data frame where each row is some permutation of (an ordered) list of elements. The same row can **not** have the same element twice, but it may not have any. For example if a row contains five values and the possible values are "alpha" through "epsilon", {"alpha","beta", ",","} is allowed, {"beta","alpha", ",","} is also allowed, but {"alpha","alpha", ",","} is not. It cannot appear in the frame, by construction.

The rows of the data frame can therefore be un-ordered. What I want is to sort each row according to a predefined relation, eg a dict. For example, the data frame may look like

```
yy = {
    'x1':         ['alpha', '', 'beta', '', 'gamma'],
    'x2':         ['',  '', '', '','alpha'],
    'x3':         ['',  'beta', '', 'alpha',''],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(yy)
df
```

The given (= predefined) order is `sort_order = {'alpha': 0, 'beta': 1, 'gamma': 2}` and using this the desired output is

```
# Desired output
yy = {
    'x1':         ['alpha', '',     '',     'alpha',   'alpha'],
    'x2':         ['',      'beta', 'beta', '',        ''],
    'x3':         ['',      '',     '',     '',        'gamma']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(yy)
df
```

How is it possible to do that? My actual data frame is not really big, but it's still ~ 20K x 200, so it pays to (1) avoid looping over all rows and use if-then statements to order each row within each loop iteration and (2) pass all the columns at once and not have to specify something like `[['x1', 'x2', ... , 'x200']]`.

Answer (score 0):

First create helper `Series` by ordering with same index like columns names and then per rows test if match by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set not matched values by empty string:

```
sort_order = {'alpha': 0, 'beta': 1, 'gamma': 2}

s = pd.Series(list(sort_order), index=df.columns)
df = df.apply(lambda x: s.where(s.isin(x), ''), axis=1)
print (df)
      x1    x2     x3
0  alpha             
1         beta       
2         beta       
3  alpha             
4  alpha        gamma
```

Alternative solution with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = pd.Series(list(sort_order), index=df.columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where((df.apply(lambda x: s.isin(x), axis=1)), s, ''), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
print (df)
      x1    x2     x3
0  alpha             
1         beta       
2         beta       
3  alpha             
4  alpha        gamma
```